# Validate ReCaptcha inside FOSUser login form

Tags: php, symfony, recaptcha

I am using `FosUserBundle` and `EWZRecaptchaBunde`.
I overrided the login form to add the recaptcha field. Everything is working.

The problem is that the login form validation do not consider the reCaptcha field and if the user enter a correct login and password he will be logged.

I have made a sort of ***pre login*** event that should test if the captcha is valid or not but my ***pre login*** is a `listener` that extends `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` and I really don't know how to get the captcha value.

This is the `attemptAuthentication` method that override the other one, in my ***pre login*** listener

```
protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    // I only have added this (return null everytime)
    $captcha = $request->get($this->options['recaptcha'], null, true);

    if ($captcha && true !== $captcha) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid captcha.');
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` they use something like this `$username = $request->get($this->options['username'], null, true);` to get `username` and `password` value. This get the values from `input` who have `_username` or `_password` names (this are defined in the listener constructor).

I tried with the same method as the other field to find the captcha value but the captcha field is a `div` with an `iframe` inside, so I get `null` everytime because it doesn't find anything.

How can I get the value returned by this captcha (true or false, I'm using the new reCaptcha) ?
I really don't know how should I do to find this value and if this possible of course.

It is maybe not the good method to do to allow captcha validation in login form.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to check manualy that given recaptcha code is valid you can create your own authentication handler. That handler have to implement `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface`.

There are two methods that needs to be implemented:
`

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    // validate captcha code
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    // validate captcha code
}`
```

In order to use Session and Routing you need to extend handler class with `ContainerAware` then inject these services via constructor of your class.

Register your custom handler as a service:
`

```
...
    #app/config/security.yml
        security.authentication_handler:
            class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        public: false
        arguments:
            - @router
            - @session
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [@service_container ] ]
```

To enable handlers add following lines to your `security.yml file`

`...
    form_login: 
        success_handler: security.authentication_handler
        failure_handler: security.authentication_handler`

You could also consider using Google reCAPTCHA.

Comment: The bundle gives a validator who check if the captcha is ok or not, this validator is used on other forms when I put the `IsTrue` constraint on the captcha field. But this validator is not used on login form. Is your method can be used with this custom validator ?